# Efficient way to find factorial

Tags: c++, data-structures

What is the efficient way to find factorial of a number other than normal recursive function and loop method? Since the normal method takes too longer to produce output is there any way to reduce the time complexity than the recursive and loop methods?If not why?

Comment: What's your problem that you are trying to solve using factorials?

Comment: See http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/FastFactorialFunctions.htm

Comment: How long do you "have"? A trivial implementation in `gmp` gets it done in 0.9 seconds on my machine (obviously, different processors/machines will have different performance).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since 79! is 1.711E98 you only need a list of 79 numbers to just use a lookup table.
The factorials are listed at: http://www.tsm-resources.com/alists/fact.html in integer format or at http://home.ccil.org/~remlaps/javascript/jstest1.html in scientific format, so it is just "cut and paste"

Comment: Lookup table is exactly what I would have suggested.

Comment: But I don't see where he's getting the 79 from.  By my calculations (which could easily have an off by one error), for 32 bit integer, 12 entries should suffice; for 64 bit, 20, for IEEE float 34 and for IEEE double 170.

Comment: The links don't work! :(

Answer (score 2):

If you want to calculate many factorial values, then caching the values as you go along is an option.

If you just one a single calculation of `factorial(n)`, then loop is probably the best you can get. You could possibly get more out of the processor by a bit of loop unrolling (calculating two or four multiplications at once), but it's unlikely to work for very large factorials, since multiplication in itself becomes a lengthy series of instructions.

As far as I'm aware, there is no "magical" math to calculate a sequence of `12 * 13 * 14 * 15` or similar faster than multiplying them together.

Comment: `gamma( i - 1 ) == fact( i )`.  Calculating `gamma` isn't necessarily simple, but for large `i`, it's significantly faster than just multiplying (and you don't get the accumulated rounding errors that you'd get in the loop: remember that each time you get a rounding error, it is multiplied by all of the following terms).

Comment: You only get rounding errors in floating point. Floating point can't be used beyond a couple of hundred or so.

Comment: About 170, for the usual `double`.  But using `gamma` should avoid the problem even there.  (I'm not too familiar with how `gamma` is calculated, but a quick glance at the sources from the g++ library gives the impression that it is decidedly faster than `O(n)`, which is what the loop will give.

Comment: Yes, but it's also inaccurate - and we're talking 100000!, not 170. Which is WAY outside all floating point ranges that I've familiar with (it's approximately 35K digits). Big number calculation is required for this. I think gamma is calculated using the Stirling approximation found elsewhere. In which case it suffers from the same problem of being inaccurate, and rather complicated to calculate. I wrote a naive implementation with gmp, and it takes 0.9 seconds to calculate 100000! iteratively with all the digits (it then added 0.8s to actually display it, but if I send it to /dev/null...)

Comment: Using `gamma` should be _more_ precise than multiplying.  As for 1000000!, will that even fit in memory (assuming some sort of `BigInteger` class)? (At any rate, I'd definitely implement the gamma function and use it, rather than looping over the multiplies.)

Comment: I guess it depends on why you need a big factorial value - is roughly right good enough, or do you need all the digits? Mine uses big integers, yes.

Comment: `gamma` will give you all of the digits, as exactly as you want.

Comment: Then I'd like to see what it does that is different from factorial Fancy writing it up?

Comment: The space and the available characters mean that I can't describe it in detail here, but it's a well known mathematical function, which has been available on Unix platforms since I've worked on them.  You'd have to check one of the standard reference works for the full details (including how to implement it).

Answer (score 2):

You may use [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) to evaluate a large factorial.

Comment: When `n` gets into the 1000's type of numbers, doing exponents, logarithms and such gets rather messy too, since they get outside of the numerical range of integers.

Comment: @MatsPetersson But any extended precision/size package should already have them.  Something using this or the gamma function will certainly perform better than just looping, although they are decidedly more complex to program.

Answer (score 2):

Since one of your comments says you want to find 100000!, this answer covers huge factorials.

If you do not need an exact answer you can use [Stirling's Approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)

If you want an exact answer you need to use an arbitrary precision math package like GMP
[arbitrary precision math package](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic)

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced that calculating large exponents and square roots, etc, is that much easier in big number math. My naive approach to string math is currently into 12 minutes to do 100000! (10K is relatively easy, takse about 5 seconds, but as the number gets longer, caches are not big enough, copying takes longer, etc, etc)

Comment: Using the ln(n!) = n*ln(n)-n form of Sterling's, for n=10000 we get ln(10000!) ~= 82103.  So 10000! ~= e^82103 ~= 10^35657 ~= (2^32) ^ 3701 (assuming my high school math has not failed me). So it is quick to get a very coarse approximation.  I agree if you want all 35657 digits of the answer, Sterling's is not the way to go.  But now we know we can compute the answer in ~3701 4-byte words of memory using GMP.

Answer (score 0):

No, not really. If you are concerned with the run-time cost, it can be reduced with a look-up table (which requires that you use pre-calculated values).

To store every factorial may require too much memory, so lets store every k:th factorial.
This will require the program to perform up to k multiplications in runtime.

Let's say your runtime performance requirement limits you to 1000 multiplications for each factorial. Then you need to pre-calculate and store 1000!, 2000!, 3000! and so on up to the upper limit you want to support (available memory will limit you).

Since factorials quickly become larger than the native data types you need a class that can handle large numbers. I have assumed that ther exists such a class and that it is called `BigInteger`.

```
BigInteger preCalculatedValues[] = { new BigInteger("1"), new BigInteger("<value of 1000!>"), and so on... }

BigInteger factorial(int n) {
  int pre = n/1000;
  int i;
  if (pre > LARGEST_VALUE_HANDLED) { 
    // Either throw an exception or let it take longer. I choose to let it take longer.
    pre = LARGEST_VALUE_HANDLED;
  }
  BigInteger result = preCalculatedValues[pre];
  for (i = pre * 1000 + 1; i <= n; i++) {
     result.multiplyWith(i);  // This operation is probably overloaded on the * operator
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of calculating very large factorals is to use
the gamma function.  On the other hand: it won't be as fast as
the table lookup (as proposed by others); if you're using built
in types, you'll need tables of:

```
for 32 bits: 12 entries
for 64 bits: 20 entries
for float:   34 entries
for double: 170 entries
```

(There may be an off by one error in the above tables.  I wrote
the code to calculate them very quickly.)

For `double`, and possibly for `float`, the usual loop method
will probably introduce too many rounding errors anyway.  If you
don't want to use a table, and you have C++11,
`exp( lgamma( i + 1 ) )` should do the trick.  (If you don't
have C++11, you might have the `lgamma` function anyway.  It's
in C99.)

If you're dealing with some sort of extended range type, you
might have to implement `lgamma` (and `exp`) for your type.